# ember js, trying to use ember-jquery-mobile add-on

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ember.js

I'm trying to import [ember-jquery-mobile](https://github.com/albertogonper/ember-jquery-mobile) to my ember project, so I followed the instructions and simply ran:  `ember install ember-jquery-mobile`.

This got my project no to run any more and I just get the error:

```
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-zV2EpgWN.tmp/0/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-zV2EpgWN.tmp/0/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:892:18)
        at ConcatWithMaps.keyForFile (/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:90:20)
        at Array.map (native)
        at ConcatWithMaps.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:112:65)
        at /Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:493:16)
        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:505:17)
        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:476:11)
        at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/giulio/Documents/rails/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

any clues?

Comment: The readme on ember-jquery-mobile mentions running `bower install --force-latest`. Did you try that? https://github.com/albertogonper/ember-jquery-mobile#installation

Comment: Yep, did that too... but no luck

Comment: I'd try removing ask dependencies and installing again. `rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp` then `npm cache clean && bower cache clean` then `npm install && bower install` and restart your server.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that, and it didn't improve.